# Validate to ensure that text has been entered in a text box before pressing a button that moves them to a new form

Tags: c#

I have a text box called txtName and a button called btnPlay. How do i ensure that they can't press the play button and play the game without entering their name. The players name is then stored in a text file

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        File.AppendAllText(@"..\..\..\Files\playerdetails.txt", txtName.Text);
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are now ready to play");
            Form1 myForm1 = new Form1();
            myForm1.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check it in the button handler:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name!");
        return;
    }
    File.AppendAllText(@"..\..\..\Files\playerdetails.txt", txtName.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("You are now ready to play");
    Form1 myForm1 = new Form1();
    myForm1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines too

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text.Length > 0;
 }
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, because it shows the user whether it is possible to press the button or not. Having the button enabled all the time, suggests that it can be pressed and that the game will start. Instead the user might get a message - this can be frustrating.